# Disable Photos auto-import when connecting memory card

Tags: photos.app

I use Lightroom and external CF card reader on a MacBook with 10.11.6. Every time I connect a memory card the Photos import dialog pops up, which is quite annoying since its starts reading from the memory card and often locks up.

How do I disable it globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the auto pop box in iPhotos , In the preference you can turn it off the auto import option. [Link](http://www.mcelhearn.com/os-x-prevent-iphoto-from-opening-automatically-when-you-sync-an-ios-device/)

Comment: Unfortunately this sets the flag per volume (CF card) - not for the card reader itself. But its still a working solution unless you have deal with tons of cards.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is incorrect.  The global solution is for iPhoto, not Photos. There is no equivalent global setting in Photos.

Answer (score 0):

The common answer to this question is to uncheck the auto-launch box in Photos. The problem is that every time you format your memory card in-camera, Photos sees it as a new device and you have to start over.

The only way I have found to disable the auto-launch of any program when inserting a memory card is by going to Terminal and following the instructions here:  [Stop Photos Auto-Launch](http://petapixel.com/2015/12/21/stop-apple-photos-from-auto-launching-in-os-x-with-one-command/)

Comment: Ideally, add a summary of the steps described on the link, because links tend to rot.

Comment: Ideally, someone with greater knowledge of Terminal commands could explain it. I don't feel qualified to summarize and explain those instructions that alter the guts of the OS, other than to say I tried it myself and it works.